# Blocking a CALL or SMS in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, callblocking

I am .NET developer and currently working on App to develop on Windows Phone 7. I am looking for something in Windows Phone 7 using which the user can block the calls or sms from a specific number.

Is there any way one can achieve the Call Blocking and SMS blocking in Windows Phone 7, If it is there then please help me.

Thanks
BHAVIK GOYAL

Comment: I don`t think so, that there`s someting like that. Your App executes in a sandbox and will just be deactivated if a call comes in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to do this with Windows Phone 7.

If you must have this functionality then WP7 is not the right platform for you.